# Are there any differences between Project DIVA Future Tone and Project DIVA Arcade Future Tone?

Tags: version-differences, project-diva-future-tone

Project DIVA Future Tone is supposed to be a direct port of Project DIVA Arcade Future Tone for the PS4, but are there any differences between the two? (like modules and songs)